# Excel VBA (error 'Method 'Open' of Object '_Recordset' Failed')

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I use ADODB Function To my  Code To display the Data From MS Access Database To UserForm Listbox in excel vba and when i try to run the code its say error 'Method 'Open' of Object '_Recordset' Failed' i think the cost of an error is the SQL inner join Query
Sub read0()

```
dbPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\POS-V1.accdb" ' Database Path

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
con.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = con
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.BARCODE, Products.ProductName, Products.Description, Categories.CategoryName, Products.Size, Products.Stock, Products.Cost, Products.Price " & _
                   "FROM Products INNER JOIN Categories ON TRIM(Products.CategoryID) = TRIM(Categories.CategoryID)"
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open cmd

If Not rst.EOF Then
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.Clear
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.AddItem "ProductID"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 1) = "BARCODE"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 2) = "ProductName"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 3) = "Description"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 4) = "CategoryName"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 5) = "Size"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 6) = "Stock"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 7) = "Cost"
    frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(0, 8) = "Price"

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    rowIndex = 1

    Do Until rst.EOF
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.AddItem rst.Fields("ProductID").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 1) = rst.Fields("BARCODE").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 2) = rst.Fields("ProductName").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 3) = rst.Fields("Description").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 4) = rst.Fields("CategoryName").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 5) = rst.Fields("Size").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 6) = rst.Fields("Stock").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 7) = rst.Fields("Cost").Value
        frmMain.lstbox_itemlist.List(rowIndex, 8) = rst.Fields("Price").Value

        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

rst.Close
con.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: If you are quering "\POS-V1.accdb" i thing is better to tag the question as "Access"

Comment: Can you run that query directly by creating a query and pasting SQL view?

Comment: I tested your code with that SQL syntax and it works.

Comment: i think the method  are the cuase of an error